# Elements from one list to another

Tags: list, f#

I have this problem:

I have a list with let say `[2;1;2;1;4;1]` and a int, I want to add the integer number to a new list if it accours in the first list, that means that the result should be a new list with `[1;1;1]` if the integer is 1, I believe i can use tail-recursion and I have used google and looked for something similar here at stackoverflow but I can't find it.

Comment: You need to show what you have found so far. Ideally an example of your attempt to solve the problem and why that attempt failed. Alternatively you can link to resources that answered similar questions and again why they don't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the built-in higher-order functions:

```
[2; 1; 2; 1; 4; 1] |> List.filter (fun e -> e <= 1)
```

This is tail-recursive for you already!

Comment: Well if I can avoid the inbuilt functions it would be better but this is good but I would like to use this: 'let duplicate z list = list |> List.filter (fun e -> e <= z)' and make something more advanced. I want a function of type int->int->bool that is going to test the integer argument against all elements of the list and the elements that yields true when the operator is applied should be in the return list.I have this code 'let eq x y = x = y' and 'let lt x y = x < y' and I want the result to be: 'func eq 2 [1;2;4;2;5] => [2;2]' 'func lt 2 [1;2;4;2;5] => [4;5]'. Not aloved to use lt and eq

Answer (score 1):

```
let findOccurences e = List.filter ((=) e)
```